# C#: Run multiple tasks in sequential order when debugging

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

In my release code all scheduled tasks can be managed by the task scheduler and it can put them on any thread it likes. They have no dependency or concurrency issues to each other.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
public void Run()
{
    foreach (var task in this.Tasks)
    {
        task.Start();
    }

    var runningTasks = this.Tasks.ToArray();

    var completedTasks = new List<Task>();

    while (runningTasks.Any())
    {
        try
        {
            var taskIndex = Task.WaitAny(runningTasks, this.ParentCancellationToken);

            var task = runningTasks[taskIndex];

            completedTasks.Add(task);

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                this.CancelGroup(runningTasks);
            }

            runningTasks = this.Tasks
                .Except(completedTasks)
                .ToArray();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) //happens in WaitAny() when _parentCancellationToken is cancelled
        {
            this.CancelGroup(runningTasks);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is a real hassle when trying to debug due to the constant context switches. I know that you can freeze the other threads but given enough threads it's still inconvenient.

What I would like to do is to force them into a nice sequential order instead of parallel'ing them when being in debug mode, ideally without a lot of compiler switches.

Currently I have a derived class and a compiler switch where the class is instantiated. Here I do this:

```
public override void Run()
{
    foreach (var task in this.Tasks)
    {
        task.Start();

        var runningTasks = new List<Task> { task };

        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (this.ParentCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                this.CancelGroup(runningTasks);

                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            this.CancelGroup(runningTasks);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a more convenient option

I know that there is something like

```
task.Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

but I'm not sure if it still wouldn't switch between tasks even when they are all on the main thread.

Comment: Remove all this code and use `async/await`. Tasks aren't threads and don't have to be started. There's almost never any reason to use cold tasks.

Comment: I cannot use await in the default code because all tasks have to run in parallel, I need Tasks there. I'm just looking for an easy way to deviate from the original code into debug code without having to change too much.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What you posted is based on an incorrect assumption of what tasks are. There's no `just` here, this is completely wrong

Comment: In the production code I have 15 tasks that can be deployed to any thread by the parallel task library. Which they are. But when debugging I want to debug the code of one task and one task only and I do not want to click "next step" (F10) and land in a completely different task because the thread scheduler decided it's time to give another thread a bit of CPU time.

Comment: You keep trying to treat tasks like threads. They aren't. I repeat, what are you trying to do? Explain the high level problem, not how you assume it's solved. Are you trying to run 10 jobs in the background? Create a job queue? Execute 100 things, 10 at a time? All of these have easy solutions that have nothing to do with what was posted here. If you want to execute a bunch of things in the background for example, put them in a `List<Action>` and then call `var tasks=actions.Select(act=>Task.Run(()=>act(),cancellationToken)); await Task.WhenAll(tasks,cancellationToken);`.

Comment: If you want to execute a few at a time, or process a bunch of items at a time, you can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, eg `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(action,(act,token)=>Task.Run(()=>act,token));`. If you have asynchronous methods the code is actually cleaner, eg `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls,async (url,token)=>{ var json=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url,token); .... })`

Comment: A buffered job queue with a configurable number of workers is already available using the `ActionBlock<T>` class. If the worker methods generate results you can use `TransformBlock<TIn,TOut>`. These Dataflow classes can be combined in processing pipelines with each block using a different number of worker tasks and buffer sizes

Comment: I have 15 jobs that need to run independently of each other parallel to each other. At the very end there is a union point after which the code continues on a common path again. However, if one of the job fails, all other jobs need to be cancelled as well as there is no point in continuing. All jobs have the same code but with different parameters. If you set a breakpoint in the code and then start to debug it, the debugger will randomly switch between jobs unless you freeze all other threads in the threads window of Visual Studio and you can concentrate on the one job you want to look into.

Comment: Use a CancellationTokenSource and pass the same token to all the function calls that *generate* the tasks. Don't treat `tasks` as your job lists, they're just a *promise* that something will complete in the *future*. In fact, in other languages like JavaScript or C++ tasks are called promises. `Task.Run`, `Task.WhenAll`, `Task.WaitAll` etc accept a CancellationToken parameter. All asynchronous methods that support cancellation do it through a CancellationToken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256666/discussion-between-dee-j-doena-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: If the methods themselves need to trigger cancellation, they should do it by calling [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=net-8.0`)

Comment: The existing APIs [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach)/[`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) should be sufficient for your case. There is no need to write complicated multithreaded code yourself when there is a simple solution available. Just set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` when debugging.